# Python script for controlling the AR Drone doesn't work

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a simple python script to takeoff the drone.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Empty

rospy.init_node('cipek')

empty = Empty()
takeoff = rospy.Publisher('/ardrone/takeoff', Empty, queue_size=1)
land = rospy.Publisher('/ardrone/land', Empty, queue_size=1)

takeoff.publish(empty)
print("works")
```

I have created a package with catkin. In one terminal I run `roscore`, in the other `rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver`  and in third `rosrun my_package script.py`. The python script is runnable (I have run `chmod +x` on it), and it works because it print out "works". The problem is that the drone doesn't react at all. However, when I run `rostopic pub ardrone/takeoff std_msgs/empty "{}" --once` in the console it works perfectly. Any ideas what is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325491/python-script-for-controlling-the-ar-drone-doesn%27t-work/) by [Cipek](https://answers.ros.org/users/42571/cipek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Any ideas what is wrong?

your script terminates before ROS has any chance of getting your message to any potential subscribers. Setting up subscriptions takes time.

It would be best to wait for subscribers to have connected using [get_num_connections()](http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Topic-class.html#get_num_connections) and only `publish(..)` when there is at least a single subscriber.

After that, wait a little and only then exit the script.

---

Edit: I would add a sleep in there, just so we don't hog the CPU while waiting for a subscriber:

```
while takeoff.get_num_connections() < 1:
    rospy.loginfo_throttle(2, "Waiting for subscribers on /ardrone/takeoff ..")
    rospy.sleep(0.1)
takeoff.publish(empty)

 # give subscriber 2 seconds to receive the message (this much time is not needed,
 # but just to be on the safe side)
 rospy.sleep(2.0)
```

Notice also the `rospy.loginfo_throttle(..)` to inform the user about what is going on.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cipek](https://answers.ros.org/users/42571/cipek/) on 2019-06-12**:
Could you modify my code so it works as you said? I want to make sure I have it correctly.

**Comment by [Cipek](https://answers.ros.org/users/42571/cipek/) on 2019-06-12**:
Nevermind. Got it running with: `while takeoff.get_num_connections() >= 1: pass takeoff.publish(empty)`

**Comment by [Cipek](https://answers.ros.org/users/42571/cipek/) on 2019-06-12**:
Should I do a similar loop before every command, like fly forward, land, etc?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-12**:
No, not necessarily.

Right now you're using a time-based approach. What would be better would be a state-based approach: send a command and then, instead of assuming it will be executed, verify that is has been executed by checking the state of the system you're trying to control.

It's unfortunate the ardrone interface is topic based for these things, as topics don't guarantee delivery or processing of messages, but you'll have to make do, as that is what it is.

**Comment by [Cipek](https://answers.ros.org/users/42571/cipek/) on 2019-06-12**:
Do you know how to check the state of the drone?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-12**:
I have almost zero experience with drones, much less with ardrones, so I wouldn't know.

**Comment by [Cipek](https://answers.ros.org/users/42571/cipek/) on 2019-06-12**:
Okay. No worries. I'll do some research then.